# Game Engine does not conserve momentum

Tags: game-engine, physics

I am trying to setup some physical simulation in the BGE where it would be best if the the total energy of the system is conserved. However, if looks like I can't get the physics engine to keep the energy level even remotely constant.

Things I've done:

- Render Settings: Toggled Use framerate
- World: Gravity set to 0, played around with the FPS and physics accuracy, sleep disabled.
- Dynamics: All Damping set to 0, tried 'rigid body' as well as 'dynamics'
- Material: Friction set to 0
- Material: Elasticity of Collision set to 1

Here is a test [file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1742071/StackExchange/energeConservationTest.blend): Layer 1 and 2 has two separate test scenes. There is a notable increase in the speed of all objects after each collision (as seen in the console window)

Am I missing something? Or am I asking too much from a game-centric physics engine?

Comment: If you can't find an answer here, I've gotten lots of good info & discussions on BlenderArtists.org:

Comment: This is their game engine support forum: http://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?12-Game-Engine-Support-and-Discussion

Comment: Thanks, if this doesn't work out, I will try BA.

Answer (score 3):

I've written a Blender/Bullet simulation of a [Newton's Cradle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_cradle) that doesn't conserve energy.  Here's two animations that illustrate the problem:

[image: Newton's Cradle animation] [image: Newton's Cradle animation]

It's all done with rigid bodies, and the wooden top piece doesn't participate in the physics.  The initial angle of the first ball is an adjustable parameter - 90 degrees in the first animation, 60 degrees in the second.  You can reproduce everything by running [this script](http://www.freesoft.org/software/blender/cradle-16may2014.py) in Bullet 2.69.  Make sure the Tool Shelf is open to get to the simulation controls.

I suspect that it's all the same problem.

Comment: Looking at this my best bet for the cause is collision error.

Answer (score -1):

Wala, the following video shows an amazing tutorial. I am very impressed.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_SEkirxgNU